# Stroke rendering inside of Topojson area. How to change the style of the full shape?

Tags: d3.js, stroke, topojson

I am having an issue with changing the stroke of an individual element in a Topojson file where my mouseover is not altering the stroke of the full shape.

A visual is probably best:

[image]

I would like every border element from the county shape area to receive the same stroke on mouse-over. Instead, I am getting this odd effect where only part of the border changes stroke.

Comment: It's because of z-sorting; other shapes happen to be on top of this shape and they're covering up part of the stroke. The fix is to always move the moused-over shape to the front. In SVG, you do it by making its DOM element the last child in its container. A way to do it in d3 involves using `selection.order()`.

Comment: @meetamit Thanks. That is very interesting. How would you sort the shapes such that the highlighted section goes to first in the order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using a solution like this, [referenced here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917072/choropleth-maps-changing-stroke-color-in-mouseover-shows-overlapping-boundari)

```
.on("mouseover", function(d,i) {
    d3.select(this.parentNode.appendChild(this)).transition().duration(300)
        .style({'stroke-opacity':1,'stroke':'#F00'});
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Say all your drawn shapes are in a data-bound d3 selection called `shapes` (which you create using the usual enter, update, exit flow). Then something like this should work:

```
shapes.on('mouseover', function(d, i) {
  // d is the datum of the hovered shape

  // data is all the data currently bound to shapes
  var data = shapes.data();

  // this'll sort the data such that the hovered d is last in the array
  data.sort(function(a,b) { return d3.ascending(a == d, b == d); })

  // now that the data is sorted, reorder the shapes to match
  // the order within data.
  shapes.data(data);// NOTE: there's a good chance this line is not necessary. Try taking it out.
  shapes.order();
});
```

Comment: That makes sense. It does not seem to have made a difference, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hmm, not sure why. Can't help you unless you post some code or make a fiddle.

Comment: Does the d refer to the current hovered shape's data? Wouldn't that just have all the data?

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917072/choropleth-maps-changing-stroke-color-in-mouseover-shows-overlapping-boundari