# moving path to front changes selection?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i'm struggling to understand the following behaviour: i have two maps (based on topojson-data, visualised through d3), and on mouseover over certain parts of map1, the corresponding parts of map2 should light up. i got it to work with changing the style (opacity or fill), but now i wanted to highlight the borders of each map-part.

as seen for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17917072/choropleth-maps-changing-stroke-color-in-mouseover-shows-overlapping-boundari) one needs to move the specific path to the front to make all the borders visible. this is no problem for the area where i move the mouse across (using this), but when i select the corresponding part of the other map, it works one time and after that other parts get selected - so my guess is something is messing with the selection.

here is the code:

```
.on("mouseover",function(d){
var old=d.properties.iso;  //this is the identifying number of the map-part(s)

sel=svg2.selectAll("path")
  .data(datastore2015.features)
  .filter(function(d){return d.properties.iso==old;})
  .node();  //here the corresponding part(s) get filtered

d3.select(sel.parentNode.appendChild(sel)).classed("high2",true);  //and this moves it to front and highlights the borders
```

on mouseout, it just resets:

```
.on("mouseout",function(d){
svg2.selectAll("path").classed("high2",false);
```

when i log the data to the console it seems that each mouseover moves +1 entry through the dataset, starting by the first entry the mouse moved over. i could not figure out why this happens and how to avoid it.

i'd appreciate any ideas you could give me, mainly i'd like to understand what's going wrong and why.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

so i found my error, calling the data-variable once again seems to have messed things up - somehow i was under the impression that i need it, but it works just fine this way:

```
sel=svg2.selectAll("path").filter(function(d){return d.properties.iso==old;}).node();
d3.select(sel.parentNode.appendChild(sel)).classed("high2",true);
```

sorry for the bother, i didn't see this possibility before.